# Parse.com - Best way to get objectID for Parse.Model Object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I keep trying to grab the objectId for the Parse.com Parse.Model object I'm working with. The only success I've had it to use the following:

```
this.model.toJSON().objectId
```

This seems to complicated and slow since I should be able to just access a property on the object. Attempts to the use the following have only resulted in a undefined value.

```
this.model.get("objectId")
```

Any ideas on what I've missed for accessing this value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the object id through the `id` property:

`this.model.id`

Comment: Thanks. That's the solution I was looking for. I kept sticking with "objectId" since that what the column is in the data browser and the key in the json data.

Comment: It's covered in the JavaScript SDK guide here: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-retrieving